# unable to write authority file /home/administrator/.xauthority-n

Tags: virtualization

I had some problem today `/usr/bin/xauth: unable to write authority file /home/administrator/.xauthority-n`

I realized that the disk got full somehow, however, I added more space in the Proxmox UI and rebooted the VM.

After rebooting I still see the amount of storage space I had before, but on the Proxmox UI, I see the new amount of storage.

How can I update the Ubuntu terminal to recognize the additional space to the same storage he had before?

Comment: When you "added more space", did you only increase the size of the virtual disk, or did you also resize the partition + filesystem and/or LVM volume? See for example [Resize disks: General considerations](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Resize_disks#General_considerations)